# Weakness in double encryption

Tags: cryptanalysis, des, multiple-encryption

In the "Introduction to Cryptography: With Coding Theory" by Trappe and Washington, in the chapter about DES algorithm the authors say that:

> "If double encryption is equivalent to single encryption, then the
>   (single encryption) cryptosystem is much less secure than one might
>   guess initially"

The authors don't explain what this means and why. Are you able to tell me ?

Comment: This is the third time you've asked the same question nearly word-for-word.  What's going on?

Comment: It's connected with the other question (that thanks to your help i've understood). But it's another question

Comment: OK, can you clarify what the difference is, then?

Comment: This question does appear to be different.  The format's the same, including quoting the same source about the same general topic, but this one's asking about a different quote.

Comment: @AleQuercia If you give the question a more descriptive title, then it being a non-duplicate would seem more obvious.